# Custom Label in Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Can anyone help me with the syntax for using a custom label in a Javascript button.  Essentially, I am trying to direct users to different pages based upon whether the Opportunity Record Type contains the 15 character ID string contained in a custom label.  My code is below:

```
    if('{CONTAINS(Opportunity.RecordTypeId,$Label.ENT_CommitRT_ID)}' == 'TRUE'){
window.open('/apex/opportunityProductEntry_Exclusive?id={!Opportunity.Id}')
}

else{
    window.open('/p/opp/SelectSearch?addTo={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}')
}
```

The problem is that no matter what record type the Opp has, it always defaults to else condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two notable problems with your logical evaluation:

- You're missing the bang character (`!`) required in merge syntax.
- You don't need to compare strings. Just use the Boolean output directly (`if({!...})`).

Instead of:

```
if ('{...}' = 'TRUE')
//    ^ missing !
```

Use:

```
if ({!...})
//  ^^ don't wrap in quotes
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, when I remove the single quotes from my initial condition, it works!

Comment: Yeah because `if ('false') { ... }` will fire. It needs to be `if (false)`.